# GridView out of memory with large number of ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I'm developing a Universal Win App and the issue is present on both platforms. I've a **ObservableCollection** with products, object properties are bound from xaml **DataTemplate** and ObservableCollection is set as ItemsSource to **GridView**.

```
private ObservableCollection<Product> productList = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
```

Bound products have images too.

```
<Image
    CacheMode="BitmapCache"
    Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
    Stretch="Uniform" />
```

**GridView**

```
<ScrollViewer
    x:Name="ProductList_GridView_ParentScrollViewer"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    Grid.Row="1">
    <StackPanel
       VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
       <Viewbox
           AllowDrop="False"
           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
           Stretch="UniformToFill">
               <GridView
                   x:Name="ProductList_GridView"
                   Margin="15,9.5,15,0" />
      </Viewbox>
   </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Also I've a kind of pagination setting which make request each time scrollable height is equal to vertical offset. And I'm adding new items to **ObservableCollection** by doing

```
foreach (var item in requestResult.products)
{
  productList.Add(item);
}
```

this seems to work fine until i reach certain number of items. After that the app just crashes. My app's memory consumption reaches as high as 800Mb's before crashing on 2GB ram device. On 512Mb ram it crashes a lot earlier.

How can I fix the issue? Do I need to change the way I did this pagination. Or can it be fixed with small changes. I guess the problem is with Image but not sure. Isn't **CacheMode="BitmapCache"** supposed to fix the memory problem?

Comment: You should use BitmapCache only when animating controls. In this case it is not necessary to use it. Do you have virtualization enabled?

Comment: You should have the ItemsPanel of your GridView set to `ItemsStackPanel`

Comment: Forgot to mention i have ItemsPanel as ItemsWrapGrid. But i am using the MaximumRowsOrColumns property of it. ItemsStackPanel doesn't have that.

Comment: thanks Kristian but i didn't understand what do you mean by virtualization?

Comment: Can you please provide the XAML where you use the GridView?

Comment: @KristianVukusic updated my question with xaml including GridView

Comment: You may also want to implement ISupportIncrementalLoading on your data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GridView` [virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780657.aspx) is broken because you are wrapping it in a `ScrollViewer` and all items are rendered at once (and using much more memory).

If you only leave the following `XAML` you will have no more memory problems:

```
<GridView
   x:Name="ProductList_GridView"
   Margin="15,9.5,15,0" />
```

Comment: thanks this is a good point i didn't know about. and seems to fix over memory issues very well. But i have to use Viewbox to make my gridview two columns with horizontally strech (so fill the screen fully). Do you know any proper way to achive this too?

Comment: Specify *HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"* and *HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"* on the `GridView`